# Detectar cambios en mi formulario para que apenas se modifique algún campo activar un boton

Tags: javascript, css, angular

estoy tratando de hacerlo con pristine pero siempre me retorna  un valor verdadero, me gustaria sugerencias de como saber si se modifico algún dato de mi formulario para poder activar el botón

```
seria algo como esto, aunque el formulario es mas extenso, el formulario contiene datos al cargar  y al tener alguna modificación el boton de grabar deberia habilitarse, de esta manera he probado y no me funciona

<form [formGroup]="miFormulario" >  
<input type="text" formControlName="descripcion">

 <input type="submit"[disabled]="miFormulario.pristine"
   name="grabar" id="grabar"value="Grabar" >
</form>
```

también he probado así y llamando a esta función desde el botón de esta manera

```
[disable]="yourCheckMethod()"



 yourCheckMethod(){
        let botonDisabled: boolean = false;
        botonDisabled=  this.miFormulario.pristine;
        return botonDisabled;
    }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si, se puede con reactive forms, pero pon un poco más sobre lo que estas haciendo para poderte ayudar.

Comment: muchas gracias de antemano, alli edite y agg y fragmento de codigo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `miFormulario.touched` o `.untouched` para detectar el cambio.

```html
    <form [formGroup]="miFormulario">
      <input type="text" formControlName="descripcion" />
    
      <input
        type="submit"
        [disabled]="miFormulario.untouched" // La otra es !touched, cuestion de gustos nada más.
        name="grabar"
        id="grabar"
        value="Grabar"
      />
    </form>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo [funcional aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-umxntk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

> #### Opcional
>
> Te recomiendo que actives el botón cuando tu formulario sea válido con `miFormulario.valid`. En mi opinión es más natural.